# SSIS File System Task moving file to another folder using UNC Path

Tags: ssis-2012

In my new SSIS package I have tried using both File System task and Script task to move a file to child ("DONE") folder once the file has been processed and I get an error saying "Could not find part of the path" I set the path to variable 100% the path exists so what I am doing wrong.

The file is being processed by a batchfile that loads the file thru a 3rd party system into an SQL server database. If the file was locked it would surely say locking error and the 3rd party system would not show successful import.

Answer (score 0):

I just fiddled around with my package tried to run it locally but disabled the batch call, (this was running the script so one line call File.Move (Source, Destination) where I changed the destination to not include the filename so the path only) and initially it was circling in an infinite loop. So I stopped it and ran a few more times and every time post the first run it was throwing a Target of Invocation error whatever that is. Then I changed it back to File System Task and now it worked locally. I deployed to the server it worked also. I reenabled the batch call redeployed and it worked on the server go figure. So I have no idea what I really did for it not to work. Moral of the story step away and come back don't trust yourself and reconfigure.

Now that I can put it down to mostly likely a human error or maybe a bug in SSIS that you do something else as in reconfigure it now starts to work or was it simply removing the filename from the destination path works for File System task only I will never know but I will probably delete this post as I don't think it adds anything useful.